# How to find a asp control id using java script?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using following code to find control id.

```
alert(document.getElementById("<%# TextBox1.ClientId %>").value )
```

but this code is giving error "object required".
Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a control with that name...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use

```
alert(document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientId %>").value )
```

or set  `ClientIDMode="Static"` for textbox and then

```
alert(document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1 %>").value )
```

Also check [How to: Access Controls from JavaScript by ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410598.aspx)

Comment: should be `"<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>"`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use '=', not '#'

```
alert(document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientId %>").value );
```

The "`<%#`" symbol is an inline expression used for databinding.

The "`<%=`" symbol there is used for display / translation purposes.  It basically does a `Response.Write` of just the value of the [`.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property of your server control.

See [this article on inline expressions in asp.net](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

replace # with = in the given statement 
updated statement is

```
  alert(document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientId %>").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementById('Id of control').value )
```

You can get the exact id of control by view source.

Comment: This is correct but with MasterPage ID mangling this can be a pain and make your code look horrible.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of JavaScript, which is on the client side `"<%# TextBox1.ClientId %>"` has no meaning because this will be translated by ASP into to a different ID based on how you configure  `TextBox1.ClientIDMode` for which you have 4 modes described here [Control.ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)